# Using webpack production builds

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am currently writing my small library and using `webpack` as a module bindler. I want to have my have my bundle file and `import` or `require` from it my bundled code.

My webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = (env = {}) => {
const inProduction = env.production;
const loaders = ['babel-loader'];

if(!inProduction) loaders.push('eslint-loader');

return {
    entry: ['babel-polyfill', './index.js'],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        filename: 'build.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: loaders
            },

        ],
    },
    node : {
        fs : "empty",
        child_process : "empty",
        process : true
    },
    watch : true
}
};
```

my `index.js`:

```
'use strict';

 import dotenv from 'dotenv';
 import QueueFacade from './src/PriorityQueueFacade';


 dotenv.config({ silent: true });

 export default QueueFacade;
```

My aim for now is to be able to require it like `const q = require('build.js')`, and then create a new instance as `const queue = new q(params)`. So it is like for any other libraries we use.

The problem is that after running `webpack build` and trying to run the code above I am getting the error `q is not a function`.

How can I adjust or my imports/exports  to build a working production built?

Comment: Do you know how `new` keyword workds, in any language, and what new should be used on?

Comment: small hint: classes

Comment: @PlayMa256, yeah, I know that. And  I `import` a ES6 class from other modules.